# What is the cardinality of the equivalence class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, cardinals, infinity

Consider this relation:

$$R = \left\{ {\left\langle {f,g} \right\rangle  \in {{\left\{ {0,1} \right\}}^N} \times {{\left\{ {0,1} \right\}}^N}|\exists k \in N\left| {\left\{ {i \in N|f(i) \ne g(i)} \right\}} \right| = k} \right\}$$

It's actually saying, $\left\langle {f,g} \right\rangle  \in R$ iff $f$, $g$ don't agree with each other countable times ($k \in \mathbb{N}$).

What is the cardinality of the following equivalence class:
$$\left| {{{\left[ {\lambda n \in N.o} \right]}_R}} \right|$$

Obliviously, it has to be at least $\aleph_0$, We can demonstrate it by the series $1000...,11000...,111000...$

But how to show it's exactly $\aleph_0$?

Comment: The definition of $R$ is unclear. Are you missing some $\{\}$ perhaps?

Comment: What's unclear exactly? I think it's fine.

Comment: I dont' understand also who is the class you ask for the cardinality

Comment: $|\exists k\in\Bbb N|i\in\Bbb N|f(i)\neq g(i)|=k$ does not "compute".

Comment: are you sure to have spelled everything correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** The set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable.

Comment: Isn't the set of finite subsets is: $\left| {P(N)} \right| = {2^{{\aleph _0}}} = \aleph $

Comment: No. $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ also have **infinite** subsets, and infinite subsets whose complement is also infinite.